# CakePHP form validation against javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, validation, cakephp

I am developing a cakephp (`2.5.6`) application where user can entry comments, blog posts and more. The users can use html markup (h1, h2.., quote, ..).

How can i add security to the form inputs so a user can not add javascript code like `<script>alert('foo');</script>` or anything else.

I have tested it with a simple `$this->Form->input('description');`. Now if i display the description with `echo $data['Post']['description']` the alert is displayed on page refresh.

What is the common way to prevent this? Does cakephp provide any helpers or functions?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html - have you taken a look at the documentation?

Comment: Maybe use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) or write custom validator which will be checking if there are not allowed tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should push **all** output on a webpage through `h()` which is the Cake shortcut for [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). Even output you've fetched from an API or a hardware sensor. Who tells you they can't give you malicious data? Most fundamental security rule: Don't trust **any** data input in your system.

If you need a more detailed sanitizer HTML Purifier which is a lib [and CakePHP plugin for it](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-html-purifier) that allows you to come up with specific filtering. For example disallow `<script>` but allow `<b>` and `<a>`. It can even filter allowed HTML attributes. Read the documentation.

Comment: I see that this function also works with arrays. Should i use `h()` in view or controller? For example: `echo $this->set('post', h($post));` or `echo h($post['Post']['description'])` ..